# The most professional way to edit an EditText borders

Tags: android

Simply, I would like to change the borders of an EditText.

I don't know if I can do that by putting something like /res/drawable/editborders.xml

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#8b3732" />

        <solid android:color="#ff000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Please not that the above code is nothing but an example of what I was giving a try.

I want the border to be more like a gradient rather than a simple color. For example:

[image]

If we look closer we'll notice a gradient :

[image]

This is how I want to do it, the professional way, Any expert can solve my issue?

Comment: I'm a little rusty in Android layouts, but afair backgrounds scale with the edittext - perhaps you could put the gradient there?

Comment: please can you clarify? what do you exactly mean?

Comment: yes sorry, perhaps you could make a transparent .png containing only the glow/gradient, then use that as background behind the edittext - it should scale as the edittext gets smaller/bigger (maybe put it in a layout that holds the edittext)

Comment: i like the idea! i'll give it a try and i'll also try the 9 patch suggested below... and i'll get back to you guys informing you about what happened with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 9-patch image as a background of your `EditText`.

Comment: can you please be more specific? just give me a hint as i have no idea how to work with 9-patch

Comment: There is a 9 patch tool in your SDK you can use it to cretae 9 patch drawables. Look here [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) and here [link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

Comment: Thank you! I like the link, i hope it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradient to achieve something similar to that:

```
<gradient
android:angle="270"
android:startColor="#67e203"
android:centerColor="#51b500"
android:endColor="#59c601"
android:type="linear"
/>
```

Hope it helps.